# Is my analysis of this recurrence relation correct?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

The following recurrence relation,

$$T(n)=16T(\frac{n}{4}) + n^2$$

has been given to me to be solved via the Master Theorem. I'm pretty sure this is a case 2 situation, since

$$\log_4{16} = 2$$ and

$$\log_n{n^2} = 2$$

Where $b = 4$, $a = 16$, and $c = 2$, such that $f(n) = n^c$

What I'm *not* sure about is the end runtime complexity.

What I've come up with so far is

$$T(n) = \theta(n^2log_2{n})$$

...since the Master Theorem states that, for case 2 situations, $f(n)$ must be within the set of $O(n^clog^kn)$, where $k$ is some constant in which $k \ge 0$.

My reasoning was to substitute 0 for $k$, which led to $\log_2^1{n}$ in the result, as the result requires that $T(n) = \theta(n^clog_2^{k+1}{n})$.

In a nutshell, while I know the first portion of the analysis is correct, and that this *is* a case 2 situation, am I correct in the reasoning behind the logarithmic portion in the ending runtime analysis?

Comment: Either your proof works, or there is some gap. In both cases, you should be able to find out yourself. We have a policy of not grading homework on this site.

Comment: Does our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) help? @YuvalFilmus, I think this question contains a (just barely) specific enough question about the attempt to be allowable.

Comment: "What I'm not sure about is the end runtime complexity." A recurrence is just a way of defining a function: it has nothing to do with runtime complexity *per se*, since that function could be used to measure anything at all. It's a bit like saying "I'm trying to work out what the total distance is in 753+3858" -- the numbers in the sum could stand for anything.

Answer (score 2):

The Master theorem (roughly) states that in case two,

$\qquad\displaystyle f \in \Theta\left( n^{\log_b a} \log^{k} n \right) 
  \implies T \in \Theta\left( n^{\log_b a} \log^{k+1} n \right)$.

That is, once you have identified the recurrence as case two by finding $k \geq 0$ so that $f$ is in this $\Theta$-class, the theorem *automagically* spits out the final result -- no further reasoning on your part necessary.

To be specific, in your case $a=16$, $b=4$ and $f : n \mapsto n^2$; therefore, $f \in \Theta\bigl( n^{\log_b a} \log^{k} n \bigr) = \Theta\bigl( n^2 \log^{k} n \bigr)$ with $k=0$ and you get

$\qquad\displaystyle T \in \Theta(n^2 \log n)$.

Two comments:

- You use base $2$ for the logarithm in the final result. It should be $b=4$ (check the proof of the Master theorem) but it luckily does not matter; all logarithms share the same $\Theta$-class.
- You talk about "runtime analysis"; this is not specific to runtime functions, and the recurrence at hand is unlikely to accurately describe the runtime of any algorithm. See also [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis).